# Exporting Map Series to multiple PNGs using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, export, png, map-series

In ArcGIS Pro, how can I export a Map Series to multiple PNGs?

in the GUI, there's an easy option to export to multiple PDFs, but not for PNGs.

I found [this article](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/mapseries-class.htm) (under "MapSeries example 2") that references some `arcpy` code, but it's not exactly obvious how to use it.

PS: I've been able to answer this question by myself, but I just wanted to leave this here as a record for others who might have a similar problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code can be used to export a MapSeries to several PNGs. It primarily uses `arcpy`'s [`exportToPNG` function](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/layout-class.htm) (look at the documentation link provided for more details about the function's parameters).

The `INSTRUCTIONS` portion of the code has instructions on how to use it and what parts of the code in the `INPUT DATA` you'll need to adjust to make it work for your specific project.

I hope the comments and examples help make this process easier.

```py
####################
### INSTRUCTIONS ###
####################

# Code adapted from:
# https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/mapseries-class.htm
# Documentation on the the Layout's exportToPNG method can be found here:
# https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/layout-class.htm

# To use this script, open ArcGIS Pro, go to the "Analysis" tab and, under the 
# "Geoprocessing" group on the far left, click on the "Python" item. A new
# Python notebook will pop up. Paste the full contents of this script into the 
# cell and update three important parts in the `INPUT_DATA` section:
#
#    - The `output_folder` variable:
#         This is where we determine the folder where the PNGs will be saved.
#         By default, the code will export the PNGs to the same folder where 
#         the project file (.aspx) is stored, in a sub-folder called "Output". 
#
#    - The `output_png_fname_pattern` variable:
#        This is where we determine the filename pattern that the 
#        newly-generated PNGs will follow. Special instructions for this part 
#        are given below.
#
#    - The `layout_number` variable: 
#        This is where we determine which of the project's Layouts has the 
#        MapSeries we want to use for the PNG exports. Most of the time, you 
#        can just leave this set to 0. But if that doesn't work, you might need
#        to tweak it a bit. If that's the case, try changing this value from 0 
#        to 1, 2, 3, etc.
#
# Important note: 
#    This code WILL NOT overwrite the PNG files in the output folder. 
#    If you want to overwrite those files, you will need to manually delete 
#    the unwanted PNGs before executing this code.

#######################################
### LOADING LIBRARIES - DO NOT EDIT ###
#######################################

import arcpy, os, sys, pathlib

########################################################
### INPUT DATA - YOU CAN MODIFY THE CODE CHUNK BELOW ###
########################################################

# As mentioned above, you will likely want to change the output folder desired.
# The code below defaults to exporting the PNGs to the same folder in which the
# project file (.aspx) is located, under a new subfolder called "Output". 
# If you want it to be exported to somewhere else, just update the 
# output_folder variable so that it points to exactly where you want the PNGs
# to go.
output_folder = pathlib.Path(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])) / "Output"

# The output_png_fname_pattern variable describes the filename pattern for the 
# newly-exported PNGs. You can use the MapSeries' main layer's 
# attributes/columns to generate these filenames. To make use of them, the 
# attribute/column names should be placed in curly braces {} and have the term 
# "this_row." prefixed to it.
#     
# Example: 
#    Suppose that your MapSeries is based on the following layer 
#        https://services.arcgis.com/KTcxiTD9dsQw4r7Z/arcgis/rest/services/TxDOT_Districts/FeatureServer
#    This is a layer containing polygons indicating the locations of TxDOT 
#    Districts. The layer that has columns called DIST_NBR, DIST_ABRVN and 
#    DIST_NM (among several others). 
#
#    This is how the PNGs will be named depending on the different 
#    ways you define the output_png_fname_pattern variable:
#
#      output_png_fname_pattern="{this_row.DIST_NBR}_{this_row.DIST_ABRVN}.png"
#          -1_PAR.png
#          -2_FTW.png
#          -3_WFS.png
#          -....
#
#      output_png_fname_pattern="MapSeries_{this_row.DIST_NM}_Texas.png"
#          -MapSeries_Paris_Texas.png
#          -MapSeries_Fort Worth_Texas.png
#          -MapSeries_Wichita Falls_Texas.png
#          -....
output_png_fname_pattern = "{this_row.DIST_NBR}_{this_row.DIST_ABRVN}.png"

# As mentioned above, this code assumes that the project only contains one 
# Layout and that it already has an active MapSeries within it, which is the 
# one we will use to export all the PNGs. If your project has multiple Layouts,
# you might need to tweak this value. Try changing it to 1,2,3, etc.
layout_number = 0

####################################################
### MAIN CODE - NO NEED TO CHANGE ANYTHING BELOW ###
####################################################

# Making sure the output_folder variable really is a pathlib.Path object
output_folder = pathlib.Path(output_folder)

# Creating folder path in case it doesn't exist yet
os.makedirs(output_folder, exist_ok=True)

# Detecting the characteristics of the current project and fishing out the
# layout within it.
p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
l = p.listLayouts()[layout_number]

# Diving into the MapSeries and looping over its pages
if not (l.mapSeries is None):
  ms = l.mapSeries
  if ms.enabled:
    for pageNum in range(1, ms.pageCount + 1):
      # Updating the currently-viewed "page" of the MapSeries
      ms.currentPageNumber = pageNum
      
      # Fishing out the data for this specific row/page of the MapSeries
      this_row = ms.pageRow
      
      # Establishing the pattern for the PNG filenames
      output_fname = output_png_fname_pattern.format(this_row=this_row)
      
      # Exporting the currently-viewed "page" to PNG
      l.exportToPNG(out_png=output_folder / output_fname)
```

Answer (score 0):

Great code above by Felipe. Worked for me. However just to extend that code, it would be nice to add a comment on the exporttopng part to show how to change some of the default settings. Would make this code snippet more complete.

Probably not all the parameters but at least the DPI.

https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/exporttopng.htm

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/261432)

Comment: Hi [@Kam](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/129434/kam)! Thanks for the response! 
In the body of my original answer, I already do mention that the reader can find extra details on the `exporttopng` function on the ArcGIS website and link to it: 
>It primarily uses [arcpy's `exportToPNG` function](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/layout-class.htm) (look at the documentation link provided for more details about the function's parameters)
Also, the link in your answer is for an older version of the `exporttopng` function from ArcMap, not the arcpy one that I use.